# Makefile rule for copying files with multiple extensions into target directory

Tags: makefile

I would like make to copy files from the source directory into a target directory. And i would like to avoid copying unchanged files. Therefore, I am trying to utilize make function of checking for newer files with a `%.:%.` rule.

Now, in this instance, the source and target EXTENSION are the same. There are object files elsewhere but not for the graphical assets.

I use `make` to copy images.

```
TARGET := target

SOURCE := source
GRAPHICS := $(foreach dir,$(SOURCE), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.jpg ) $(wildcard $(dir)/**/*.jpg ) $(wildcard $(dir)/*.png ) $(wildcard $(dir)/**/*.png ) $(wildcard $(dir)/*.gif ) $(wildcard $(dir)/**/*.gif )  )

JPG = $(GRAPHICS:.jpg=.tmp)
PNG = $(GRAPHICS:.png=.tmp)
GIF = $(GRAPHICS:.gif=.tmp)
```

And then use the following rule to copy files into target directory:

```
%.tmp:%.jpg
    find $< | cpio -p -d -v $(TARGET)
```

### Questions

1. Is it possible to string replace the TARGET directory here
2. and thereby use the make newer capability?

I tried

```
 JPG = $(GRAPHICS:$(TARGET).jpg=.tmp)
```

But that fails with `No rule to make target`. Is it only possible to compare source and object in the same directory?

Can one make a rule such that the source and object are the same extension?

```
%.jpg:%.jpg
```

The closest I can come up with is:

```
$(TARGET)%.jpg:%.jpg
```

but that never runs. Even after a clean.

Comment: This question is unclear. Could you give an example of a path you expect in `GRAPHICS`, and what you want in `JPG`? And what is the purpose of the `%.jpg: %.jpg` rule?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

This 'setup' remains the same.

```
TARGET := target

SOURCE := source GRAPHICS := $(foreach dir,$(SOURCE), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.jpg ) 
$(wildcard $(dir)/**/*.jpg ) $(wildcard $(dir)/*.png ) $(wildcard $(dir)/**/*.png ) 
$(wildcard $(dir)/*.gif ) $(wildcard $(dir)/**/*.gif )  )
```

Now add a prefix to ALL (space separated) values in the $GRAPHICS string

```
TARGET_GRAPHICS := $(addprefix $(TARGET)/, $(GRAPHICS) )
```

- Note that patsubst aka -- `TARGET_GRAPHICS := $(patsubst %, $(TARGET)/%, $(GRAPHICS) )` -- only worked for the first entry. Perhaps I was doing it incorrectly.

Provide a pattern match for each file type. Here do whatever you wish. In my case, copy the input into the target directory. cpio will make the needed directories. cp -p might also work as needed.

```
$(TARGET)/%.jpg : %.jpg 
     @echo "--- .jpg copying " $< " to " $@ " into dir " $(<D)
     @find $< | cpio -p -d -v $(TARGET)


$(TARGET)/%.png : %.png 
    @echo "--- .png copying " $< " to " $@
    @find $< | cpio -p -d -v $(TARGET)

$(TARGET)/%.gif : %.gif
@echo "--- .gif Copying " $< " to " $@
@find $< | cpio -p -d -v $(TARGET)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want the copy of `d1/d2/f.png` into `out/d1/d2/f.png` to make use of *make*'s dependency checking?

```
out/d1/d2/f.png: d1/d2/f.png
out/d1/d2/f.png: 
    cp $< $@
```

Adding a jpg file `d3/g.jpg` say,

```
out/d3/g.jpg: d3/g.jpg
out/d1/d2/f.png: d1/d2/f.png

out/d1/d2/f.png out/d3/g.jpg: 
    cp $< $@
```

We can express this more cleanly with a static pattern rule.

```
out/d3/g.jpg out/d1/d2/f.png: out/% %
    cp $< $@
```

Nice. So adding your `${GRAPHICS}` and fleshing things out a bit

```
outdir := out/
targets := $(addprefix ${outdir},${GRAPHICS})

.PHONY: all
all: ${targets} ; : $@ Success

${targets}: ${outdir}%: %
    echo $< | cpio -d -p ${outdir}
```

Parallel safe too, so `make -j9` will exercise your 8 CPUs nicely.